# What exactly are the atoms in a discrete distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If I build a word count on a corpus of text, are the atoms of this distribution the unique words themselves?

I ask because the definitions I read of atoms in a probability distribution (such as [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Atom)) are too abstract.

It's the excellent answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72668/how-to-compute-kl-divergence-when-pmf-contains-0s) StackExchange question that prompts me to ask. It gives an equation "where |x| is the number of atoms in the discrete distribution". Interpreting atoms as the set of words in the corpus is certainly consistent with the context but I can't find anywhere that says this definitively.

Similarly, my interpretation that atoms as the possible outcomes for any probability distribution is supported by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710492/difference-between-the-support-of-a-discrete-random-variable-and-the-atoms-of-it?rq=1) StackExchange question but I am still not sure.

Can anybody please assure me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atoms of a measure space are, in some sense, the smallest non-null sets in the space.  Any set contained within an atom has zero measure, and a set is not an atom if it contains a measurable set that has non-zero measure.

For counting the words in the corpus you are also correct that distinct words are atoms: though words may contain other words (for example, *the* appears inside *other*) they do not contain distinct words (surrounded by non-word characters) for the purposes of word-count$[1]$.  In such a corpus, words are atoms, and then phrases or sentences are built out of atoms; paragraphs out of phrases and sentences, etc.

You don't say, but I suspect, that you're planning on using a Bayesian classifier, in which case words are definitely the right atom to select.

$[1]$ Language is tricky: a hyphenated word can certainly be claimed to contain at least two distinct words, and some languages use symbols as "letters" (e.g. representing a glottal stop as an apostrophe) that might be thought to be non-word characters in other languages.  But for word-count, you can almost certainly treat a distinct word as: being at the start of a line and followed by a punctuation mark or whitespace, being both preceded and succeeded by punctuation marks and/or whitespace, or being at the end of a line and preceded by punctuation or whitespace.  You will have to decide if you want to special-case the hyphen as the above rules will treat the hyphenated word as two (or more).  You might also want to note English has a couple of special case words as well, like stun's'l and fo'c'sle that will get turned into three words.